# what is the best way to split data and why?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, train-test-split

I am taking an online course in deep learning. they used the following code for determining train, validation and test data: (The shuffling step is before it which I did not write here)

```
samples_count = shuffled_inputs.shape[0]

# Count the samples in each subset, assuming we want 80-10-10 distribution of training, validation, and test.
# Naturally, the numbers are integers.
train_samples_count = int(0.8 * samples_count)
validation_samples_count = int(0.1 * samples_count)

# The 'test' dataset contains all remaining data.
test_samples_count = samples_count - train_samples_count - validation_samples_count

# Create variables that record the inputs and targets for training
# In our shuffled dataset, they are the first "train_samples_count" observations
train_inputs = shuffled_inputs[:train_samples_count]
train_targets = shuffled_targets[:train_samples_count]

# Create variables that record the inputs and targets for validation.
# They are the next "validation_samples_count" observations, folllowing the "train_samples_count" we already assigned
validation_inputs = shuffled_inputs[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]
validation_targets = shuffled_targets[train_samples_count:train_samples_count+validation_samples_count]

# Create variables that record the inputs and targets for test.
# They are everything that is remaining.
test_inputs = shuffled_inputs[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]
test_targets = shuffled_targets[train_samples_count+validation_samples_count:]
```

My question is why we don't use train_test split in sklearn? then we can make validation from train data.
what is the advantage of splitting data like that?
I know they choose the best way to code. So I thought maybe there is an advantage to do that. Using train_test split is easier. we do not need to shuffle data manually .

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking with this is separating your data in training, validation and testing. There is no general census in how this proportions should be.

A lot of people use the Pareto principle 80% training and 20% testing, but there is no specific reason why you should use this. Validation data is used to detect overfitting in your model, so it shouldn't be any of the data used on training and testing, and because you want to maximize the amount of data to train your model, then some part of the testing data is used.

Hope it helps you to better understand why this numbers are used.

Comment: What I usually do is using train_test_split from sklearn. then I get 10% of train for validation. ( before setting the model). So you say it does not matter how we do that? from memory or speed or ....